# How to fix "<style> isn't allowed in <td> elements"

Tags: css, html

I created an email in a drag and drop software that gives you html and I'm trying to fix the errors given to me by EmailOnAcid. I'm pretty new to html and css but I do have some experience. I've tried a couple different fixes but they haven't worked. As far as I can tell this isn't actually effecting the email format but I would like to know how to fix it.

I've tried doing the styling in the head but that just gives me different errors. I'm sure it's a pretty simple fix but i'm used to using stylesheets and the code generated by the drag and drop editor is not formatted for readability.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=""><tr><td>

<p style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
<!--[if gte mso 11]>
<style type="text/css">

table
{
  border-spacing: 0; 
}
table td 
{
  border-collapse: separate;
}
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if !mso]><!-->
<style type="text/css">
table
{
  border-spacing: 0;
} 
table td 
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
```

Comment: In page-style tags go in the header section. EX: `<head><style> table {border-spacing:0;} </style></head>`

Comment: Sorry, I just read that you tried that and it didn't work. That's very strange indeed. Have you tried linking to an external style sheet?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Maybe I just didn't do it right I'll give that another try tomorrow when I go into work. Unfortunately since it's being sent as an email external style sheets aren't widely supported.

Comment: I see... I will scour the internet for any other observations of the same behavior, as  well as possible fixes. I'll let you know if I find anything

Comment: HTML emails are not web pages. Only a few select tags and CSS properties work across all email clients. Others being simply stripped or ignored. One of the most mind boggling ones being `margin` not working in a significant number of Outlook versions. While there are many tools out there to help you find the coverage of a particular html tag or CSS property across email clients, I recommend Google's [email markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/). Note many email clients strip `<style>` tags, which is why inline styling is recommended in emails.

Comment: In this case, the particular <style> block isn't even necessary; all the styles in it are already taken care of by the attributes on the <able> tag. What I'd be more worried about is the use of proprietary MSO styles like `mso-line-height-rule: exactly;`, which aren't supported by other email clients at all and that don't seem to trigger a warning.